# Pass a variable to the n.setSelected method?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I currently have 2 ag-grid instances on a page, and a row selection via the right table then causes a row to be selected in the left table as well.

My issue is I need to know which table (left or right) caused the left table selection for other state.

To help understand, the sequence of events is as follows:

```
// set state globally and pass into both LeftGridWrapper and RightGridWrapper
// THIS STATE CONTROLS WHAT ROWS ARE SELECTED IN THE LEFT MENU
const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState([]);

return (
  <div>
    <LeftGridWrapper setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds}  selectedIds={selectedIds/>
    <RightGridWrapper setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds} />
  </div>
)
```

```
// In the RightGridWrapper
onRowSelected = (params) => {
  ...
  // causes selection in LeftGridWrapper
  setSelectedIds([...selectedIds, params.data.someId])
}
```

```
// In the LeftGridWrapper
useEffect(() => {
  leftGridOptionsApi.forEachNode(n => {
    if (selectedIds.includes(n.id) n.setSelected(true);
    else n.setSelected(false);
  }
}, [selectedIds])
```

So essentially, I would like to be able to do something like this: `n.setSelected(false, origin = 'LEFT')` and then inside the `onRowSelected` checking if the `origin` was "LEFT" or "RIGHT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume you want to highlight row with a different color on left grid if row is selected from right grid.

I would suggest this:

onRowSelect event on right grid **->** update the left grid **->** first to selected **->** then update a extra parameter to true which will let you identify that it is selected from right grid

```
    onRowSelected = (params) => {
      ...
      // causes selection in LeftGridWrapper
      leftGridOptionsApi.forEachNode(n => {
        if (selectedIds.includes(n.id){
            n.setSelected(true); // directly set left grid row selected
            n.setDataValue('colKey', value); // update a column data to true that is 
 selectedFromRight
          }
    
      }
    }
```

now on left grid **rowSelection** always update the **columnkey/parameter** to false

add a custom style for row selected  when the parameter is true **highlight red else yellow**, all this assuming you want to differentiate between from  where the row was selected from and do something accordingly.

Let me if the solution works for you or if you have a different requirement.

Comment: So what you're doing is setting the data value of the row itself? I had no idea you could that. But I think that should work for the functionality I need. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes you can modify the rowData manually :). Glad I could help.